# Change which server mailbox is associated with in Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, edb

I have restored and mounted an EDB file onto a new Exchange 2007 Server. However, the old server is still online and although all the mailboxes I need are in the newly-mounted database, in Exchange 2007 System Manager it still shows that the mailbox is associated with the old server.

If I try to "Move" the database it actually tries to copy the files from the old server to the new server, which is not necessary because they are already there - and produces and error about the mailbox on the destination already existing.

How can I simply tell Exchange (AD?) to use the new server to find the mailbox rather than the old?

Edit:

I did the restore by taking the old server offline (turning off all Exchange services), copying EDB file to the new server, restoring it with `eseutil`, and mounting it to the new server. I did it this way in part because I didn't know a better way and in part because I couldn't use `move-mailbox` as the source location had a horrible Internet connection (which is why Exchange is being moved to the new location). I had to copy the EDB from the old server to a hard disk, go somewhere with a better Internet connection, upload the EDB to the new server.

Comment: How did you do the restore? Any why did you do it that way?

Comment: @mfinni see edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yikes. What you've done is a bit bizarre and very likely going to cause problems.

I suppose you could *try* to make things work by modifying the `homeMDB`, `homeMTA`, and `msExchHomeServer` attributes of the subject AD account to refer to the server where you mounted the mailbox database you moved. I think you're in wildly unsupported territory and I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work out right.

Comment: Given that I have all the transaction logs and EDB in the target site, is there an alternative procedure I can perform?

Comment: Modify those attributes to refer to the server you've put the database on now-- you may have a shot. You'll probably need to look at a mailbox that's already hosted on that server to get all the values you'll need.

Comment: I ended up using the instructions at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125087(v=exchg.65).aspx and some other sites to get this done. It worked! (I think)

Comment: I wasn't aware that Microsoft had documented the process of manually re-homing mailboxes. Glad it worked out.

Comment: Thanks - I'll never do it that way again though.